# How to put value to an input in a table using javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geocoding

I have a map, I have a `geocodeLatLng()` function which is called inside the `getPosition()` function, but sadly the `geocodeLatLng()` or the coordinates being converted to place name and putting it in map does not work. In `getPosition()`, I can get the `currentlatlng`, my problem is how to put it in the `id=address` which is an input from a table.

I tried `document.getElementById("address").innerHTML=currentlatlng;` but it didn't work.

```
<script>
     function getPosition() {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
        currentLatLon = [position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude];
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        map = new google.maps.Map(
          document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(...currentLatLon),
            zoom: 20
          });
          var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();       
        service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        document.getElementById("curr").innerHTML=currentLatLon;
        document.getElementById("address").innerHTML=currentLatLon;
      });
    }
</script>

<form name="frm_map" id="frm_map">
    <table>
        <tbody><tr>
            <th>Address</th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="address" id="address" placeholder="Enter a location" autocomplete="off">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Radius</th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="radius" id="radius" value="1000" placeholder="In KM">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Types</th>
            <td>
                <div id="type_holder" style="height: 200px; overflow-y: scroll;"><div><label><input type="checkbox" class="types" value="amusement_park">Amusement park</label></div><div><label><input type="checkbox" class="types" value="aquarium">Aquarium</label></div><div><label><input type="checkbox" class="types" value="bus_station">Bus station</label></div><div><label><input type="checkbox" class="types" value="cafe">Cafe</label></div><div><label><input type="checkbox" class="types" value="campground">Campground</label></div><div><label><input type="checkbox" class="types" value="convenience_store">Convenience store</label></div><div><label><input type="checkbox" class="types" value="department_store">Department store</label></div><div><label><input type="checkbox" class="types" value="home_goods_store">Home goods store</label><div><label><input type="checkbox" class="types" value="meal_takeaway">Meal takeaway</label></div><div><label><input type="checkbox" class="types" value="park">Park</label></div><div><label><input type="checkbox" class="types" value="parking">Parking</label></div><div><label><input type="checkbox" class="types" value="pet_store">Pet store</label></div><div><label><input type="checkbox" class="types" value="police">Police</label></div><div><label><input type="checkbox" class="types" value="restaurant">Restaurant</label></div><div><label><input type="checkbox" class="types" value="rv_park">Rv park</label></div><div><label><input type="checkbox" class="types" value="store">Store</label></div><div><label><input type="checkbox" class="types" value="taxi_stand">Taxi stand</label></div><div><label><input type="checkbox" class="types" value="train_station">Train station</label></div><div><label><input type="checkbox" class="types" value="veterinary_care">Veterinary care</label></div><div><label><input type="checkbox" class="types" value="zoo">Zoo</label></div></div></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" value="Show" id="submit" onclick="renderMap();">
                <input type="reset" value="Reset">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <div class="ss"><a href="index1.php" style="font-size:18px; font-weight: bold; color: #666; text-decoration:none; padding-top:1000px;">HOME</a></div>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
</form>
```

Comment: User document.getElementByID() then check the return and use setAttribute.

Comment: It's an input, you want to target `*.value` instead of innerHTML

Comment: @ChrisW., I got it :) thanks. do you know why my geocoding did not worked? https://pastebin.com/tv1gbKWE

Comment: Which part isn't working? All I see is the question about getting the value in the input? Do you have a stackblitz or something for folks to debug?

Comment: I put a pastebin, I made a geocoding function that must return the place name from a coordinate it should be displayed in the map yet it did not worked, I modified the source code form google

Comment: the whole https://pastebin.com/X53ekQ9k

Comment: I don't see where you're actually geocoding and grabbing a response object, you might take another peek [at the docs](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse)

Comment: that's what I modified with my code in this part pastebin.com/tv1gbKWE from my whole code pastebin.com/X53ekQ9k

Comment: Please see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58124059/11742502